# Is there any support for Rasterlite in the Android QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, android

Is there any support for Rasterlite databases in the Android port of QGIS?

I have tried adding a raster layer as I would on desktop QGIS but there are fewer GDAL file formats listed.

Is this because rasterlite is not available on Android or is there another way to bring it in?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I don't think that Rasterlite DBs can be loaded into QGIS Android (yet). You could check by creating a project in your desktop QGIS, say a rasterlite DB file plus a QGIS project file, copying the two files to your tablet and then trying to open the project there. In QGIS desktop save the project using relative addressing of course.  Nick.

Comment: Thanks for that Nick. I have tried creating the project as you suggested and as you thought it doesn't seem to work yet. I will look forward to that one! Thanks again.

Comment: And thanks for the feedback, I suspect it's saved me a lot of pain. I was just about to try copying a 4GB Rasterlite DB to the tablet. Nick.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, this should be now possible since QGIS 2.0 for android is linked to GDAL 1.10

Comment: Do you have specific experience with adding Rasterlite layer in QGIS on the android? Please share some details!

Comment: @Simbamangu no, I'havent any such file around. but according to http://www.gdal.org/frmt_rasterlite.html it should be ok